# Python Pandas Count columns with multiple conditions and groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['LEhOc7XSE0','2020', '03', 'car'],
        ['LEhOc7XSE0','2020', '03', 'truck'],
        ['LEhOc7XSE0','2020', '03', 'bike'],
        ['LEhOc7XSE0','2020', '03', 'insurance'],
        ['LEhOc7XSE0','2020', '03', 'inspection'],
        ['iXC5AfJMox','2020', '04', 'car'],
        ['iXC5AfJMox','2020', '04', 'truck'],
        ['iXC5AfJMox','2020', '04', 'inspection'],
        ['XpLLAySojz','2020', '01', 'bike'],
    ], columns=['order_id','year', 'month', 'item_type'])
```

The column `order_id` is not unique, and describes in every row what item has been purchased with this `order_id`.

Now I want to count any the amount of orders (unique `order_id` is an order), if an order contains **either** a `car` or a `bike`, but only if the order is not made up of those items exclusively.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        ['2020','03', '1'],
        ['2020','04', '1'],
    ], columns=['year', 'month', 'count_orders_with_condition'])
```

This is how the result is supposed to look like, f.e. the `order_id = XpLLAySojz` contains a `bike`, but was omitted because it only contained of either two.
The dataframe I am operating on is rather huge, which is why using `ìterrow()` functions perform very bad here. I am a bit lost with the possibilities pandas would provide to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
import numpy as np

df['mask'] = np.where(df['item_type'].isin(['bike', 'car']), 1, 0)
mask = df.groupby('order_id')['mask'].nunique()
mask = mask.loc[mask.eq(2)]

res = df.set_index('order_id').loc[mask.index].reset_index().groupby(['year', 'month'])['order_id'].nunique()
```

Outputs:

```py
>>> res

year  month
2020  03       1
      04       1
Name: order_id, dtype: int64
```